# VueJs - I don't understand how I could pass a Boolean value to a chid component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know that the subject was certainly treated somewhere, but I really don't understand how I could pass a variable to a child component.

What I'm trying to do, is passing 'displayTogglingMenu' in the parent component to 'toggle' in the child.

**Parent component**

```
  data(){
    return  {
      selectedItem: 1,
      displayTogglingMenu: false,
      items: [
        { text: 'Home', name: 'home', icon: 'mdi-home' },
        { text: 'Courses', name: 'courses_index', icon: 'mdi-school'  },
        { text: 'Enrolments', name: 'enrolments_index', icon: 'mdi-format-list-bulleted' },
        { text: 'Lecturers', name: 'lecturers_index', icon: 'mdi-account-tie' },
      ],
    }
  },
```

**Child Component**

```
data(){
    return  {
        toggle: valueOfParentComponent,
        alertMessage: '',
        loadTable: true,
        courses: [],
        expendable: [],
        ...
},
```

Here is the component I'm trying to hide, as asked by Tim:

```
 <div class="table-container">
            <b class="circle"></b>

                <v-app>
                    <v-content>
                        <v-card>
                        
                            <v-card-title>

                                <v-text-field
                                    v-model="search"
                                    append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                                    label="Search"
                                    single-line
                                    hide-details
                                    class="search"
                                ></v-text-field>

                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>

                                <router-link :to="{ name: 'new_course'}" class="newItem">New course</router-link>

                            </v-card-title>

                            <v-data-table
                                :headers="courseHeaders"
                                :items="courses"
                                :items-per-page="10" 
                                :loading="loadTable"
                                loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
                                :search="search"
                                :single-expand="singleExpand"
                                :expanded.sync="expanded"
                                item-key="id"
                                show-expand
                                class="elevation-1"
                            >

                                <template v-slot:item.title="{ item }">
                                    <transition-group name="list" tag="p">
                                        <span class=" list-item" v-bind:key="item">{{item.title}}</span>
                                    </transition-group>
                                </template>

                                <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                                    <transition-group name="list" tag="p">
                                        <span class=" list-item" v-bind:key="item">
                                            <router-link :to="{ name: 'edit_course', params: { id: item.id } }" class="edit-btn" title="Edit">
                                                <v-icon med>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                                            </router-link>
                                            <v-btn v-on:click="deleteCourse(item.id)" class="del-btn " title="Delete"  >
                                                <v-icon med>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </span>
                                    </transition-group>
                                </template>

                                <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }"  >
                                    <td :colspan="headers.length" class="item-description" >
                                        <h4 >Course description:</h4> 
                                        <p >{{ item.description }}</p>
                                    </td>
                                </template>
                                
                            </v-data-table>

                        </v-card>
                    </v-content>
                </v-app>
            
            <b class="circle2"></b>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'd like to hide a div container component when displayTogglingMenu shifts to true, but not the entire component, using a v-if conditionnal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parent

```
<template>
  <Component :toggle="displayTogglingMenu" />
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import Component from 'Componenet.vue'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    components: {Component},
    data() {
        return {
            displayTogglingMenu: false
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

### Child

```
<template>
  <div v-show="toggle"></div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    props: ['toggle']

});
</script>
```

The value of `displayTogglingMenu` in parent will be availible as `toggle` in the child

You might need to get the value as `this.$props.toggle` depending on the context

Answer (score 0):

You could pass data from parent to child components using properties. [Here are the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Eg.

```
<child-componenet :prop-name="parent value that could also be reactive"></child-component>
```

Props are reactive so your `child-component` will react to any change on its properties, you could use the property in a `v-if` or `v-show`